# Не удается открыть apk файл на телефоне

Tags: android, flutter

Сразу после скачивания андроид не распознает apk файл, для новой версии flutter (собранной на другом компьютере) [image: не открывается apk файл]
При этом приложение устанавливается из файлового менеджера, с более ранней версией флатера такого не наблюдается. Файлы xml и build.grandle практически идентичны, в чем именно может быть проблема в  версии флатера или же не верной настройке проекта?

Comment: в proguard'e, 100% не хватает исключений для каких-то либ

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, не устанавливается с нуля или не обновляет уже установленное? Во втором случае скорее конфликт подписей приложения, так как приложение собиралось на другом компьютере.

Comment: @blind.falcon и с нуля не устанавливает и не обновляет, причем только из папки только что загруженные, если просто найти загруженный apk файл в менеджере телефона то все устанавливается и работает, с версией с другого пк такого нет

Comment: @iFr0z можете где про это модно найти актуальную информацию, в старом проекте у меня вообще не было данных для proguard

Comment: @AndreySmelik тогда всё что могу посоветовать - это почитать про изменения в новой версии флатера, чтобы понять, могло ли это как-то сказаться.

Comment: @AndreySmelik что за смартфон? И приложите файлы xml и build.grandle (которые изменяли)